# How to Change Style of CheckBox Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a Checkbox in my application, and it is meant to be checked, but also disabled. When disabled, I've noticed that the foreground of the checkbox as well as the content textbox are a darker color than when enabled. I would like to leave the checkbox disabled, but change the foreground of the content textbox to the same color as when the checkbox is disabled. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Methed you have to learn how to edit your existing/default style of your control. I can't give you the exact which will work for your but you can use Blend or Visual Studio to edit a copy of a control's current template by right clicking on the control and then selecting **Edit Style**, **Edit Template** or **Edit Additional Templates** as appropriate. In the submenu, you can select **Edit a Copy**... which will present a window that allows you to create a copy of the default (or current template/stlye if you have already modified it) and customize it.

Here is a basic tutorial for this http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/using-blend-to-find-default-style-xaml/